# OIDC Backchannel logout, how to kill browser session of a user from REST call in a JEE Application

Tags: java, single-sign-on, keycloak, xwiki

We are using Keycloak as a SSO provider to login in all our application.

We are using the keycloak logout endpoint to logout at a realm level and invalidate the access tokens of the user.

Our issue is, if a user was connected on `websiteA` and `websiteB` and logout from `websiteA`, he still have an active local session on `websiteB` through they browser.

Basically we want the user logout of the `websiteB`, a bit like if you logout from google drive you will also be logout from gmail as soon as you open gmail.com

Hopefully for us, keycloak support [OIDC backchannel logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html)

So we define that when a user logout from keycloak, a LogoutToken is sent to every app on an endpoint that we choose

let's say `websiteB/backchannel-logout`

So on my JEE application, the server well receive a LogoutToken on the url `/backchannel-logout`

This is how the logout token look FYI

```
{
  "iat": 1654177246,
  "jti": "66265511-a5fc-4f60-b5b7-65bea0e1a9e2",
  "iss": "https://mykeycloakserver.com/auth/realms/myRealm",
  "aud": "websiteB",
  "sub": "18e56c69-a90d-4f32-b76a-c9166def54d0",
  "typ": "Logout",
  "sid": "5bca2f13-f7a6-4b41-bdfc-1f7a89264149",
  "events": {
    "http://schemas.openid.net/event/backchannel-logout": {},
    "revoke_offline_access": true
  }
}
```

At this point I have a logout request from my SSO provider keycloak, containing the `sub` of the user so her unique ID and I can know the user I want to logout.

But basically I just receive an HttpRequest containing a `logout_token` from keycloak

`String logoutToken = request.getParameter("logout_token");`

Then I transform it to a JWT token object and I can read it.

But I'm completely out of any user session at this point `request.getSession()` doesn't return me at all the session that the user have open in it's browser, and I don't have any access token to use there was invalidate by the logout, I just have this logout token.

---

So all the speech above is to explain what I'm doing. But the real question could be.

How from a request not related to a browser Session could I found this session and invalidate it ?

Even if we forgout the SSO context and the LogoutToken, if as an admin I want an admin logout endpoint that accept a userId value and on this endpoint I want to kill any session of this user but I'm not this user (I'm the admin) how could I do it ?

The project is not using spring, we are using a platform called XWiki,I think it's just JEE with `javax.servlet-api` and keycloak adapter.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use front-channel logout instead back-channel. I also wanted the session details to clear that out once the user logs out from App-A. In back-channel logout you will not receive the session details.

Note that, the front-channel logout URL has a GET method.